# running a crystal report from script not from screen

Tags: crystal-reports, cygwin

Is it possible to run from a script running in Cygwin in any way a crystal report with parameters and get the report back in pdf format?
What i am trying to do is - I created a crystal report and I need it to run at night from a "scheduler".
I need to know if it is possible to run the report from a script (including sending the report 2 parameters) and have the report save to a PDF file automatically?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are Crystal Reports SDKs for .NET and Java, available on the official download pages: https://www.crystalreports.com/download/

And, of course, a wide variety of third-party tools that promise to support scheduled report generation – I'd suggest to google after "crystal reports scheduler" or take Ken Hamady's list as a starting point: https://www.kenhamady.com/productlinks/